# how to send mail through the localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

please help solve the problem.

i use webrick server on localhost. in development.rb i registered:

```
config/enviroments/development.rb:
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

i use gem devise. and i user 'forgot youre password'-function (devise-recoverable module). the result did not get to the email message. but where can I find a mark(log) that was an attempt to send a letter? whether there is a directory where they are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit your **config/environments/development.rb** file.

Here's something to get you started, add this to that file:

```
# port 3000 or whatever port you are using for your localhost
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }    
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

# this line is what you want to be true, else you won't get messages!
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: 'gmail.com' # or to whatever domain your email is
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'my_gmail_or_other_username',
  password: 'my_gmail_or_other_password'
}
```

Now, when you are moving towards production or even just pushing it to a public repository you obviously don't want to hardcode the username and password (for security purposes). For this I suggest you look up how to use **environmental variables**. The **Figaro** gem might also come in handy here and is another option.

This is the default 'smtp' way, there are other methods, such as the use of a gem as specified by the earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

try gem `mailcatcher` for development purpose.

http://mailcatcher.me/

github: https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher

This gem will provide you a tab in browser where all your emails will be there unless you delete them.